# Video files progress bar while uploading more than 100MB files using Cakephp 2.x

Tags: jquery, cakephp

Video files progress bar while uploading more than 100MB video files using Cakephp 2.x & Jquery (Not using Ajax).

I have tried with existing answer on stack-overflow but i did not find any solutions without ajax.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you uploading your files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `uploadify` if you are using jQuery? It uses a flash socket to upload the file to the server while reading from the disk, it provides realtime feedback about the files progress.

http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Barry@ I have to ask u only one thing if i implement this plugin, does it going to work on all browsers & independent of operating system.?

Comment: It should as long as they support flash

Comment: A lot of more modern uploaders (even uploadify) support HTML5 uploads.